# SSRS Reporting - How to repeat a series of different elements based on a parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with one input parameter, and based on that input, the report will have 1-3 different categories present. My issue is the report layout consists of the following elements: A header, 3 tables, and a bar chart.

What I am trying to accomplish is to repeat the above layout with ONLY categories available to the input parameter without leaving unnecessary whitespace. I've tried to achieve this by copying and pasting the layout three times and hiding the elements if the category does not exist. This works partially as I'm left with blank pages.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filling the report with a bunch of tables, try adding rows to the 1st table, adding a rectangle in that row, and adding a sub-report in the rectangle. Set the visibility of the rectangle instead of your 2 tables. This will ensure that there are no unnecessary white spaces.

Adding more than 1 table to a report has almost always ruined the layout of my reports. I've always added sub-reports instead. Even if you don't want to add a rectangle, just add a sub-report in a new row of your ONE table and that makes it a lot easier to deal with.